# Configuring DispatcherServlet for REST style URLs

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I'm trying to learn Spring MVC basics and having issues with the way URL are resolved to controllers.  I am working with this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-annotation-example/) as a springboard.  I can get it operating fine under tomcat and the url /context/welcome.htm resolves to the controller that is annotated as such:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloWorldController
```

The web.xml is configured using

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I would like to be able to type /context/welcome and resolve the HelloWorldController but this doesnt work.  I have tried setting the * but this causes the servlet to fail to load.  If someone could explain why this url pattern is invalid, and how to configure this controller to work with all requests such as /welcome and /welcome instead of just those ending with *.htm it would be greatly appreciated.  In ASP.NET MVC,a routing page was provided to debug such controller mapping issues.  What is the best way to do this with Spring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The pattern /* will put everything through your servlet.

The pattern / makes your servlet the default servlet for the app, meaning it will pick up every pattern that doesn't have another exact match.

Comment: Opted for <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> and now things work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

With your existing code you can resolve by changing the request mapping to RequestMapping("/welcome.htm") since you have made *.htm in your servlet mapping. Its all our wish how our apps url should be. The others suggestion of making /* will also work, the difference is /* allows any patter of url you hit but *.htm restricts from other patterns to be resolved.

I dont think js or css will have issues because of this because js and css does not rely on spring dispatcher servlet. js and css can be embedded without having the servlet in place. consider a standalone html has js and css, it all needs is the context of the server and not a servlet

Answer (score 0):

Try using /*

Your other pattern was not valid because it did not meet the requirements specified in the serlvet specification: https://jira.sakaiproject.org/secure/attachment/16135/servlet-2_4-fr-spec.pdf

One problem you may have using this is that requests for js files and css files are routed through the dispatcher.  You will need to setup spring to ignore requests for these files.